# How to paste from PowerPivot without Data Model

Tags: excel, powerpivot

How can I export a PowerPivot table to a new workbook without the attached data model?

Even if I click paste values, Excel makes the file unreasonably large (13MB).

Can I turn this behaviour off?

Answer (score 0):

When you say pasting a Power Pivot table, do you mean copying the table that exists in the data model, that you access through clicking the "Manage" button in the Power Pivot ribbon menu?

[image]

Or do you mean copying the values displayed in an Excel pivot table that happens to be backed by a Power Pivot model?

If the former, you can paste the table directly into a new workbook sheet (assuming it has fewer rows than Excel's limit) with no problems and no attachment made to the source workbook's data model.

If the latter, pasting values will bring over only the values, but you have to utilize the right click menu option to do so. If you just CTRL-C CTRL-V the pivot table, and then use the copy-paste context menu to change to values only, then Excel is first creating a copy of the data model in the new workbook to back the pivot table that you are pasting. Then after this action is completed, you are telling it to display values only, but Excel will not delete the data model it's just created to back the pivot table.

Comment: I was discussing pasting values from a pivot table. I still have this behaviour if I use the drop-down option "Paste Values & formatting", but only if I select a whole pivot table. If I exclude a total row or one measure, the data model does not copy

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem, it was very easy to resolve. Initially I was trying to paste as values into the destination workbook directly from the source Pivot table which automatically brings the data model across with it.

Simply make a copy of the table by pasting values into the SAME workbook as your data model. Then copy and past the new table into your destination workbook, it will just give you the values and leave the data model behind.